# Remove whitespace from ActiveX combo box and only show contents?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have a numeric list and another list next to it called an organization list, which if I happen to delete any value from the default list the other list organizes the values. I created an ActiveX combo box and selected the ranges according to the organization list, but when I delete values from the default list the ActiveX combo box leaves blanks, as I do so that it doesn't display blanks and show only the corresponding organization list values ?? I wish she wouldn't show the blanks, ??[image]

Comment: You get the blank because of the source list.

Comment: How do I remove it from the combo box?

Comment: Is there any way to remove only the spaces from the combo box and leave them on the list?